# by next to no one

Tags: meaning

Example ([Ukraine crisis: Putin shows who is boss in Crimea](http://www.bbc.com/news/world-europe-33985325)):

> As a result, the US and Europe imposed economic sanctions on Russia, and Crimea's annexation is formally recognised **by next to no-one**.

I know the expression *next to nothing* which people use to say that there is almost nothing of something. Is *next to no-one* a play on this idiom?

Comment: _Next to nothing_ doesn't mean _absolutely nothing_, but _almost nothing_. In the same way, _next to no-one_ means _almost no-one_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Next to no-one" refers to people, whilst "next to nothing" refers to objects.